# Floating element with 100% height

Tags: html, css, height

I have a element (represented as aside) that I need to span the full height of the page. However, the height is appearing to be ineffective with "height 100%".

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h18ctmfq/

```
aside{
        width:300px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#808080;
        height:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Is your body,html set to 100% height?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**JSiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h18ctmfq/1/)

Comment: I was just answering that :P +1

Comment: I've actually never used HTML as a selector before, that worked in the fiddle but not in my actual file. Is it just height, and width I would declare in both the HTML and Body tags?

Comment: @user3576711 Then it seems likely something else is affecting the element. We need more info if that is the case.

Comment: Should start closing these questions as dupes

Comment: For the `height: 100%;` to actually work, it requires your element's parent to have a fixed height as well (px or %)

Comment: Noted, tagged as such.

Comment: Got it sorted now, this answer was correct. Thanks for all the help!